# Sort file in-place

Tags: linux, string, shell, sorting, unix

I would like to sort the content and update existing file with just the sorted Data.

The `country.csv` file content is

```
India,Australia
```

The command that I am using is

```
tr , '\n' < country.csv | sort -n | paste -sd, - > country.csv
```

However, when I check, `country.csv` is empty.

Comment: ...btw, `sort -n`? Your sample data doesn't have any numeric content.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected: Pipeline setup happens *before* the programs inside a pipeline have been executed (mostly -- it's not synchronous, so there are situations where the `execve` calls for the early parts of the pipeline can still be happening while redirections for latter parts aren't complete), so your `>country.csv` wipes the file's contents before they've been read.

Write to a different output file and rename.

That is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- to let us use the below safety feature:
set -o pipefail # bashism: fail the whole pipeline if any component fails

tempfile=$(mktemp country.csv.XXXXXX)
if tr , '\n' <country.csv | sort -n | paste -sd, - >"$tempfile"; then
  mv "$tempfile" country.csv
else
  rm -f "$tempfile"
fi
```

The use of `mktemp` ensures that multiple instances of this can be running at the same time, and each will have its own temporary file -- thus, they won't damage each others' work -- and also conveys resistance against some security vulnerabilities (such as symlink attacks).

It does add a caveat, inasmuch as `mktemp` sets up restrictive file permissions -- if you intend the output file to be group or world-accessible, you may need to update these yourself.